# java-libpst outlook 2003 categories

Tags: java, outlook, pst

I was playing around with outlook pst files with [java-libpst](http://code.google.com/p/java-libpst/). All was really fine but got stuck fetching categories in outlook 2003 as it does not save it in `ColorCategories`. Is there any work around for this ? I just need to fetch the categories.

Thanks